# get undefined from a service which is being called by the service called from controller

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

During writing Unit test cases, I have been encountered into a problem where one Service is calling another Service and getting "undefined" in response. I need to Mock that "undefined" value and don't know how to do this. To completely understand scenario look at the elaboration.

**Elaboration**

Service "**B**" is called from Controller. Service "**B**" is calling Service "**A**" contains a function that returns undefined. Now i need to mock that undefined value from Service "**A**" while sitting in controller. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

i tried following implementation:

(Service A is authenticationService)

```
beforeEach(inject(function ( $controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend ,authenticationService ) {
        authenticationService = {
            getCredential: function(){
                return {loggedInUser:{id:1}};
            }
        };
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        authenticationService = authenticationService;

        httpMock = $httpBackend;
        manageTestSuiteCtrl = $controller("manageTestSuiteCtrl", {
            $scope : $rootScope, $rootScope : $rootScope, authenticationService  = authenticationService 
        });
    }));
```

but it didn't work. Then i tried spy on in test case it block

```
spyOn(authenticationService, "getCredential").and.callFake(function() {
            return {loggedInUser:{id:1}};
        });
```

that didnt help either. Any help would be much appreciated as I have been smashing my head for this issue for like a week now

Comment: Some more code could be helpful. And BTW spyOn should be defined inside the `beforeEach` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from what you have provided, I would suggest that instead of mocking the service A's method, you can mock service B's method that in-turn calls service A's method and return value undefined from it. That's because you're anyway concerned with the value returned.

The following is how I replicated the scenario you described:

**module, serviceA, serviceB and controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.service('serviceA', function(){
    return{
        methodName: function(){
            return 'something'
        }
    }
});

app.service('serviceB', function(serviceA){
    return{
        methodName: function(){
            return serviceA.methodName();
        }
    }
});

app.controller('myAppController', function($scope, serviceB){
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello World!';
    $scope.b = serviceB.methodName();
});
```

**test**

```
describe('controller: myAppController', function() {

    var myAppController, $controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend ,authenticationService, scope, serviceB;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('myApp');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _serviceB_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        serviceB = _serviceB_;

        spyOn(serviceB, 'methodName').and.callFake(function(){
            return undefined;
        });

        myAppController = $controller('myAppController', {
            $scope: scope,
            serviceB: _serviceB_
        });
    }));

    describe('initialization', function(){
        it('should initialize some variables', function(){
            expect(serviceB.methodName).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(scope.greeting).toEqual('Hello World!');
            expect(scope.b).not.toBeDefined();
            expect(scope.b).toBe(undefined);
        });
    });


});
```

Please feel free to comment on whether it helped you or not. If it didn't, please comment with the problem you are facing and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks man this works like a charm to me. also now i know some of the new things